# KnockoutJS submit binding not working with foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hello I am unable use knockout 'submit' binding with 'foreach' binding.
I cannot figure out what is mistake here.
Please help me find my mistake.

My view model is like this:

```
function poReceivingModel(){
    var self = this;
    var initial_row = new poReceivingRowModel();
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([initial_row]);
    self.saveAndAdd = function(formElement){
        alert('entered into function');
        var row = new poReceivingRowModel();
        self.rows.push(row);
    };
};

function poReceivingRowModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.building = ko.observable();
    self.isele_abc = ko.observable();
    self.isele_num = ko.observable();
    self.isele_floor = ko.observable();
};
```

And my html binded to 'viewmodel' is like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <form data-bind="submit: $parent.saveAndAdd">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- input field here -->
            </td>

            <td>
                <!-- input field here -->
            </td>

            <td>
                <!-- input field here -->
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- input field here -->
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit">Save and Add</button>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </form>
</tbody>
```

The problem is when I click on 'Add and Save' button 'saveAndAdd' function from 'poReceivingModel' is not called.
I do not get any alert message.
I tried calling that function with 'click' binding on 'button' element. The function get called this way ie I get alert message.

**UPDATE:**
In firebug I see *form* tag is closed just after 
and button is out of 'form' tag.

Comment: `<form>` elements cannot be nested within `<table>`

Comment: yes i get it. Thankk you

Answer (score 0):

I found that *form* tag cannot be used inside *table* tag. Solution is *table* tag can be put inside  *form* tag . 
If we do not want to do so we can change the table tag to div but this may not give you desired output.